# ApplicationMailer default from title not email address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, mailer

`default from` works with an email address, but when a recipient receives an email I want the title to be "Live to Challenge" not "livetochallenge.com"

[image]

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "livetochallenge.com@gmail.com" #This Line Needs An Email Address to Work
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

How can [Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) send with livetochallenge.com@gmail.com, but be shown as "Live to Challenge"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default from: '"Live to Challenge" <livetochallenge.com@gmail.com>'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Live to Challenge <livetochallenge.com@gmail.com>"
  layout 'mailer'
end
```